# Обновления Mac OS

Tags: macos

Появляется значок обновления в «Системные настройки» но при нажатии никакого обновления не появляется, а при в ручном обновлении на macOS Catalina через App Store отображается ошибка "Not available", несмотря на то, что в критериях для macOS Catalina мой компьютер должен поддерживаться.

Как обновить macOS Mojave до macOS Catalina?

[image: Окно системных обновлений, здесь видно что нет обновлений]

Comment: Инструкцию смотрели? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475

Comment: @AndrewGrow, получается для того чтобы установить Catalina мне потребуются оперативка больше чем 4гб?

Comment: Нет. Вам нужно минимум 4Гб оперативной и 18Гб свободной постоянной памяти.

Comment: @AndrewGrow,  если так, то у меня эти параметры подходят

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос в службу поддержки Apple.

Comment: Вопрос решен, скачал отсюда бета версию: https://developer.apple.com/download/